# Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException:

Tags: spring-boot, docker, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to run redis-server and my springboot app both on a container.

I was able to hit redis(present in a docker container) when I start the springboot app locally just fine, but when i put this springboot app also in the docker container then I'm unable to connect to redis and getting

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 0.0.0.0:6397] with root cause
urlshortner |
urlshortner | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
urlshortner |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
urlshortner |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779) ~[na:na]
urlshortner |   at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
urlshortner |   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
urlshortner |   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
urlshortner |   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
urlshortner |   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
urlshortner |   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
urlshortner |   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
urlshortner |   at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
urlshortner |   at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar!/:4.1.45.Final]
urlshortner |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I have tried following:

1. used docker-compose to get them onto same network

*my docker-compose*

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: urlshortner
    image: docker-urlshortner:v1
    build: .
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "10095:10095"
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/redis:/urlshortner/logs
  redis:
    container_name: myredis
    image: redis:v1
    build: ./redis
    hostname: localhost
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

*dockerfile to start springboot app*

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11
VOLUME /urlshortner
ARG JAR_FILE=target/Urlshortning-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} urlshortning.jar
EXPOSE 10095
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/urlshortning.jar"]
```

*dockerfile for running redis*

```
FROM redis
COPY redis.conf /redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

2. commented out bind 127.0.0.1 and added bind 0.0.0.0 in redis.conf

**but still getting same error**

*my redis config in java app*

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    private final String url;
    private final int port;
    private final String password;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public RedisConfig(@Value("${spring.redis.host}") String url, @Value("${spring.redis.port}") int port,
            @Value("${spring.redis.password}") String password) {
        this.url = url;
        this.port = port;
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Redis configuration
     *
     * @return redisStandaloneConfiguration
     */
    @Bean
    public RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(url, port);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(password);
        return redisStandaloneConfiguration;
    }

    /**
     * Client Options Reject requests when redis is in disconnected state and Redis
     * will retry to connect automatically when redis server is down
     *
     * @return client options
     */
    @Bean
    public ClientOptions clientOptions() {
        return ClientOptions.builder().disconnectedBehavior(ClientOptions.DisconnectedBehavior.REJECT_COMMANDS)
                .autoReconnect(true).build();
    }

    /**
     * Create a LettuceConnection with redis configurations and client options
     *
     * @param redisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration
     * @return RedisConnectionFactory
     */
    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory(RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration) {

        LettuceClientConfiguration configuration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().clientOptions(clientOptions())
                .build();

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, configuration);
    }

    // Setting up the redis template object.
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "redisTemplate")
    @Primary
    public RedisTemplate<String, Url> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Url.class);
        jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

        RedisTemplate<String, Url> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

*and my application.properties*

```
server.port=10095
redis.ttl=86400

spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.password=redisdb
```

**i have also tried changing spring.redis.host from localhost to 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1**

so when i hit it from postman I get the error

[both containers running redis and springboot app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrivJ.png)

How do i resolve this problem, any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: `localhost` in Docker generally means "this container" (and 0.0.0.0 means "everywhere"; it doesn't make sense to use it for outbound connections).  You might look at [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation to see what host names are available to make connections between containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze i agree, i tried doing that since we are binding 0.0.0.0 in redis.conf, I'll check this out, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed following which made it work

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
```

to

```
spring.redis.host=redis
```

in application.properties
and

```
hostname: localhost
```

to

```
hostname: redis
```

in docker-compose for redis